# Checking if the entered user value in an HTML input is a float number

Tags: html

I'm working on a HTML page on which i got some input controls.
In these input controls the user shall enter a float number, p.e. "1234,56" with four integers before the point/comma and two integers behind (at maximum).
How can i find out while or after entering the value, if the value is correct (number of integers before and behind the point/comma; only integers).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For future reference, you are likely getting down-voted on this question because it shows no effort on your part to even attempt your own problem. This site is for seeking help with code that isn't working right, not a site for getting freelance work done.

Comment: Sorry, i added this question just because i know that many developers have the same problem and i got a solution to it, which i wanted to make public, so that everybody can benefit of it.

Comment: Silly me, I just realized you answered your own question so that basically nullifies everything I thought was going on here. Carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do that by placing our control on a form, using the pattern property of the input and a submit-button for comparing the pattern with the value.

**First example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Checking floatnumbers</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text"
                   maxlength="7"
                   placeholder="____,__"
                   title="Please use format ####,##"
                   pattern="\d{1,4}(|\.|,)?\d{1,2}" />
            <br />

            <!-- For testing input patterns -->
            <input type="submit"
                   value="Submit" />
            <br /><br />

            <!-- Resets/clears the form -->
            <input type="reset"
                   value="Reset" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

First the input must be of type "text", not "number" as usual.
The pattern means, that the user can/must enter 1 to 4 numbers before the point or comma.
The point/comma and the following 1 to 2 decimals can be entered but it's not necessary.

If an user enters p.e. "12345" and clicks the submit-button it will show an error with the text from the property title.

Maybe some users don't want to enter a number like "1,23" but - because they are in a hurry - just ",23".
So we will take a look at the second example.

**Second example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Checking floatnumbers</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text"
                   maxlength="7"
                   placeholder="____,__"
                   title="Please use format ####,##"
                   pattern="\d{0,4}(|\.|,)?\d{1,2}" />
            <br /><br />

            <!-- For testing input patterns -->
            <input type="submit"
                   value="Submit" />
            <br /><br />

            <!-- Resets/clears the form -->
            <input type="reset"
                   value="Reset" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

As You can see the input before the point/comma has a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 4.
So it's possible to enter a floatnumber like ",23".

And if we want to enter negativ floatnumbers in the input we change the pattern to `"^[+-]?\d{0,4}(|\.|,)?\d{1,2}"` and the maxlength to 8.

**Further notice**
With the pattern above we can still enter a number like "12345" which is not correct in our case.
The correct pattern has to be: `"^[+-]?\d{1,4}((\.|,)\d{1,2})?"` or `"^[+-]?\d{0,4}((\.|,)\d{1,2})?"`